# bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(' in README of trainset14_032015.rdp for mothur

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm trying to run the README for the use of the trainset14_032015.rdp in mothur (http://blog.mothur.org/2014/10/28/RDP-v10-reference-files/), but when I get to this step it doesn't work, showing this error:

```
$ tax_file <- scan(file="trainset14_032015_rmdup.tax", what="", sep="\n", quiet=TRUE)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

So, I read and put some "" or '' at the beginning and end of the (), but it didn't work, because it now says the file doesn't exist, and it does!

```
$ tax_file <- scan"(file='/home/eugenia/Desktop/trainset14/trainset14_032015_rmdup.tax',what="", seq="\n", quiet=TRUE)"
bash: -: No such file or directory
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 3):

Those aren't bash commands, they're R commands. It doesn't say so explicitly in the README for some reason, but the `<-` is a dead giveaway. I don't know what `mothur` is but these commands from the README you show should all be run in R, not bash:

```
tax <- read.table(file="trainset10_082014_rmdup.tax", sep="\t")
tax$V2 <- gsub(" ", "_", tax$V2)    #remove spaces and replace with '_'
tax$V2 <- gsub("[^;]*_incertae_sedis$", "", tax$V2)
tax$V2 <- gsub('\"', '', tax$V2) #remove quote marks
```

and

```
levels <- read.table(file="trainset10_db_taxid.txt", sep="*", stringsAsFactors=F)
subs <- levels[grep("sub", levels$V5),]
sub.names <- subs$V2

tax.split <- strsplit(tax$V2, split=";")

remove.subs <- function(tax.vector){
    return(tax.vector[which(!tax.vector %in% sub.names)])
}

no.subs <- lapply(tax.split, remove.subs)
no.subs.str <- unlist(lapply(no.subs, paste, collapse=";"))
no.subs.str <- gsub("^Root;(.*)$", "\\1;", no.subs.str)
```

and

```
write.table(cbind(as.character(tax$V1), no.subs.str), "trainset10_082014.rdp.tax", row.names=F, col.names=F, quote=F, sep="\t")
```

All the above commands, which as mentioned should be run in R, prepare your file for use with `mothur`. They simply modify the file containing the taxonomy information so that it is compatible with `mothur`. The author of the post has chosen to use R for the formatting steps.

So, you need to run the commands I have quoted here in R (open a terminal, run `R` and paste the commands in R's interactive shell). The ones I have not quoted here should be run in bash.

Comment: Ohhh you are right! my bad!
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @EugeniaSanchez you're welcome. If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.